# Android firebase ui return statement getFirebaseRef

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am having a problem, and I'm sure it's just because I'm a beginner.

I am building an app and I want to use the FirebaseUI for logging my users in to the app. Followed the guide in the readme file, and everything looks nice, except an error saying "missing return statement" in this:

```
@Override
public Firebase getFirebaseRef() {
    // TODO: Return your Firebase ref

}
```

I really don't know what to do with this, and I have searched everywhere for an answer.
I cant figure out what the Firebase ref is, and what to do with it.
Can anybody point me in the right direction?
I'm shure it's just my inexperience in coding, but I try to learn as I go.
What i really want this to do is pop up the login screen when app is started, and when login is complete, send the user to the HomeActivity.

My complete MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FirebaseLoginBaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        showFirebaseLoginPrompt();
    }

    @Override
    public Firebase getFirebaseRef() {
        // TODO: Return your Firebase ref
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoginProviderError(FirebaseLoginError firebaseError) {
        // TODO: Handle an error from the authentication provider
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoginUserError(FirebaseLoginError firebaseError) {
        // TODO: Handle an error from the user
    }
    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoggedIn(AuthData authData) {
        // TODO: Handle successful login
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirebaseLoggedOut() {
        // TODO: Handle logout
    }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            // All providers are optional! Remove any you don't want.
            setEnabledAuthProvider(AuthProviderType.FACEBOOK);
            setEnabledAuthProvider(AuthProviderType.GOOGLE);
        }

    }
```

I know it's probably a stupid question, but as I said, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Good to see that you solved it. If you're struggling with the README, I **highly** recommend taking the [FirebaseUI codelab](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/codelabs/chat) which walks you through building your first app with Firebase and FirebaseUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
@Override
public Firebase getFirebaseRef() {
    // TODO: Return your Firebase ref
   Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://YOUR_APP.firebaseio.com");
   return ref;

}
```

Write your app name instead of YOUR_APP.

I also recommend: [Firebase Quickstart Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html)

Comment: Ah.. I feel a little dumb now..  But thank you very much for your answer! :D That of course solved it!

Comment: Does it work now? Please feel free to mark my answer as correct if it works.

Comment: You're welcome! You don't have to feel dumb. This question is ok.

Comment: It solved that problem, yes! Marked your answer as correct. Thanks again!